# How to grab gmail using php api, using oAuth?

Tags: php, api, gmail

i am able to download gmail contacts using the api. without entering the user's email and password.
Sending the authenticated request with a valid access_token i am able to grab all user;s contacts who has authenticated my application. now i want to download the users email messages from inbox.

Comment: Does the API not have a documentation where it is described how to do this
? (*If* it's possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grab contact , then YOu are familiar with oauth .so you just change url of contact graber of google to email..

I think YOu used this URL  https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/ to get contact after authentication.Instad of this use https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/ URL..

For playground visit this url : https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/-UYL6NIP2avszVz3hTNIs6Z8vmOe

Comment: i changed the url but its giving me now "Unauthorized


Error 401

" error

Comment: YOu have to first authenticate user  like contact grabber

Comment: check playground and follow same steps

Comment: i have authenticated user. but the same issue